# How to make bootstrap input calendar totally visible false in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have some situation like:

[image]

All i want to do is to remove the `x icon` also the `calendar icon`.

**My HTML**

```
<div class="input-group date form_date col-md-5" id="divDate"  runat="server" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                                                <input class="form-control" size="16" id="textBoxInspectionDate" runat="server"  type="text" value="" readonly style="min-width:200px"/>
                                                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="spanClear"  runat="server"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                                                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="spanIcon" runat="server"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" ></span></span>
                                                            </div>
```

**Here's my Code:**

```
spanClear.Visible = false;
spanIcon.Visible = false;
```

This code is working but it returns to a page look like:

[image]

My problem is:
How could i turned the calendar to `visible false` at all in code behind?

Or

Is it possible to remove a class which is `input-group date` of a div in code behind?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just give it some css with `Display: none` in codebehind by

if you wanna hide it only clientside(**Be warned this overwrites all other existing css classes**)

```
divDate.Attributes.Add("class", "imHidden");
```

css

```
.imHidden{
    display:none;
}
```

if you dont wanna render it at all

```
divDate.Visible = false;
```

**EDIT**
I must say im a little confused of what you are trying to achieve after rereading

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't need to hide all entire div. i just want   to remove the calendar class.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch So you only need a textbox? or you wanna open it only when you click it?

Comment: I need the textbox only and the value of it.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch if you dont need the calendar at all you could then just use a textbox and parse the date. Is it a disabled textbox?

Comment: i am doing it because i need the calendar at the same time it depends on the userRole Logged in. but thanks for your answer anyway. Appreciated